# ionic start with blank template giving error

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed latest node, npm and angular

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: z@0.0.1

npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9

npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler

npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler@"~11.0.5" from the root project

npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"11.0.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.9

npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli

npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~11.0.5" from the root project

npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7

npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.5" from the root project

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"11.1.2" from @angular/localize@11.1.2

npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize

npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7

npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.5" from the root project

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! See C:\Users\JatinKumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\JatinKumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-04T19_41_41_433Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: It looks like it is trying to resolve something called 'Z'. When posting questions it would be helpful to provide more detail such as what is the version of ionic you are using? What does your package.json look like. Really the more details you can provide about the steps you took to get to this point will yield better results from question.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install --force`
and then

```
npm install --save-dev --force
```

Now you can run your project!